# Why cast a ChangeEvent object to JSlider when using .getSource() Method?

Tags: java, swing, java-8, jslider

The book I'm learning from is going through event listeners and I'm confused about casting a ChangeEvent object to a JSlider object when using the event.getSource() method.  Why is this necessary?

Secondarily, does casting or method calling take precedence?  It seems like the method call occurs first if the .getSource() method is a ChangeEvent method.

I apologize for the single line of code but that's all the book has to offer outside of simple explicit directions to cast the ChangeEvent to a JSlider:

"This method is called with a ChangeEvent object that can identify the slider component that changed in cale.  Call the object's getSource() method and cast the object to a JSlider, as in the following statement:" (followed by the code below with no explanation why to cast it).

```
JSlider changedSlider = (JSlider) event.getSource();
```

Comment: Yes, the method invocation takes precedence. So not the `ChangeEvent`, but the value returned by `getSource()` is cast to `JSlider`. It’s necessary, because the compiler doesn’t know that the source of the event is always a `JSlider` in this specific program.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't cast the event to `JSlider`. It casts the **source** of the event to `JSlider`.

The source of the event **is** the slider which has fired the event.

And the cast is probably necessary because the rest of the code needs to access the `JSlider` properties/methods.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing the point of casting the source to a JSlider.  Do you know of a reason why that specific ChangeEvent would be required to be cast this way? What utility would that provide if the ChangeEvent generating JSlider has not been modified?  The focus of the last question is on the fact that the JSlider can continue to generate ChangeEvents regardless of casting.

Comment: @Christian The [`getSource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()) is defined to return an `Object` (your `JSlider` object), as defined by the API. But when you write `Object changedSlider = event.getSource()` you can't do very much with that variable, since it's type is of `Object`. You can call general methods like `toString()` or `equals()` (defined in the `Object` class), but you can't call specific methods like `getModel()` or `setMinimum()` (defined in the `JSlider` class).

Comment: Again. The ChangeEvent is not casted. What is casted is the **source** of the event. Here's the javadoc of ChangeEvent: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeEvent.html. Such an event is fired by the slider every time the value of the slider changes. Suppose the slider is used to rate a hotel. Each time the value changes, you need to get the new value of the slider to change the rating. Does the ChangeEvent class allows knowing the new value of the slider? No. But it allows getting the source of the event. And the source is the JSlider, which has the new value.

Comment: @Progman, so the return value for getSource is the generic Object and not a JSlider object? Combining that fact with JB Nizet's claim that some code later in the program may need to access JSlider properties and methods is the reason for the casting necessitates the casting?

Comment: @Christian The object returned by `getSource()` is the source of the event. In this case it **is** your `JSlider` object. If you need this `JSlider changedSlider = (JSlider) event.getSource();` or not can be easily tested if you simply remove this line. If you don't get any compile errors, you don't need this line. Keep in mind that casting an object reference doesn't *change* the object.

Comment: Yes, getSource() returns an Object. Just click the link Progman and I both gave you, and look at the javadoc. It exists for that reason. When you listen to change events fired by a JSlider, it's usually that you're interested in knowing when the value changes, but also what the new value is. Otherwise, why would you listen to such events?

Comment: @JBNizet, that is what I am interested in knowing.  Why EXACTLY would I need to cast the Object to a JSlider.  I come here for answers to questions.  The complexity of the JavaDocs are not helpful as a beginner.  That kind of answer feels dismissive and is why I have come and gone from many forums like this.  I consider it fair that the uneducated need a little more explanation to understand these "Why" questions.

Comment: I already answered that several times, and progman has, too. Because the class java.lang.Object, which is the type of ChangeEvent.getSource(), doesn't allow accessing any of the JSlider properties/methods. All Object has is hashCode, toString() and a few other very generic methods. Nothing allowing to get the new value of the slider, which is typically what you want when you listen to value changes of a slider.

Comment: @Christian The "why exactly" depends on what the application is doing. In general, however, one downcasts because they need access to members that are present on the more specific type (as explained). You mention a book you're reading; maybe it will give more complete examples further in.

Comment: And if that book is so confusing and unclear, maybe you should just read the official tutorial about sliders, which uses a concrete example with the same code: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html